# IBM Worklight Adapter Invocation is throwing UNRESPONSIVE_HOST error for Android

Tags: android, worklight-adapters, worklight-studio

I'm using IBM worklight 6.1 to develop iOS and Android mobile app.
There's a connection issue occurs for Android app on some devices (mostly Samsung devices). **The error code is "UNRESPONSIVE_HOST", the status is "-1"**.
No issue occurs on iOS devices.
Uninstall and install the app again but the issue is same.
Checked the IP Address at back-end web service logs and there's no records for that device. Therefore can assume that the app is not reachable to back-end.

That issue is solvable by doing "Factory reset" to the device but could anyone possible to share other way to solve?

Comment: Did you check your wlclient.properties in the Android project? Is the value proper? What is the exact build level you are using?

Comment: Other android devices can connect and have no issue. targetSdkVersion:19,  minSdkVersion:9, Project Build Target Android 4.2.2

Comment: My question was about the Worklight version. Complete build version. Aslo is the issue across Android devices ? Or specific to few versions?

Comment: And if the issue is specific to https or in both http and https?

Comment: Current worklight version is Worklight 6.1.0.02-20160305-1807. Device log In the log cat display _[https://xxx/android/query] Host is not responsive. Try to manually access the URL through the android emulator browser to verify connectivity._

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to check IBM worklight 6.1 host is reachable from your device is by invoking the worklight admin console from the mobile device browser.